# Interpretation of 侵入された

Tags: grammar

I was reading the web when I found this 侵入された, that was the only thing that stood there, alongside a cute GIF that may give more context. It's these one word sentences that are the hardest for me. I found it in a tweet: https://twitter.com/tengnose1988/status/1488769054512848901.

I read from here https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BE%B5%E5%85%A5%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B that 侵入された can be 受身 and 自発 (I don't think the two other ones fit in this context).

I know that 自発 is mostly used with verbs of feelings like 感じられる and 思える but according to a book I was reading not too long ago (Making sense of Japanese), things like 取れた and 釣れた also show spontaneity and those aren't verbs that has to do with feelings.

> X was invaded

> X spontaneously/couldn't help invading?

Which is the most likely to be right one. I'm assuming that maybe the tweet builds up on prior knowledge of something that I don't have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`侵入された` can only be 受身. The latter description in the second link is just explaining 助動詞 `れる` itself.

P.S. I'm not familiar with this content but it seems five girls are characters of "holoX", and their base(?) was invaded by the man "YAGOO", who produced these contents.